How to handle multiple self referencing foreign keys in Hibernate
I have a MYSQL table that has 2 foreign keys to other rows of the same table. (for simplicities sake, I have changed it to a person table, that's not what I am trying to achieve, but similar structure).
CREATE TABLE `person` (  `id` int PRIMARY KEY, `previous_person` int, `next_person` int);
ALTER TABLE `person` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`previous_person`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `person` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`next_person`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`);

My Java entity is as follows:
@Entity
@Table(name = "`person`")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "next_person")
    private Person nextPerson;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "previous_person")
    private Person previousPerson;

    public Person getNextPerson() {
        return nextPerson;
    }

    public void setNextPerson(Person nextPerson) {
        this.nextPerson = nextPerson;
    }

    public Person getPreviousPerson() {
        return previousPerson;
    }

    public void setPreviousPerson(Person previousPerson) {
        this.previousPerson = previousPerson;
    }
}

When I try to get all of the entities, I am currently getting an error Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Required array length 2147483639 + 1482 is too large
The code in the PersonService class to get all the entities is
public List<Person> getAllPeople() {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Person> cq = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
        Root<Person> rootEntry = cq.from(Person.class);
        CriteriaQuery<Person> all = cq.select(rootEntry);
        TypedQuery<Person> allQuery = entityManager.createQuery(all);
        return allQuery.getResultList();
}

How should I be defining this type of relationship, or should I not be in the first place? In the end, I would like to be able to reference person.nextPerson.someColumn, but I do not need to go down any further in the chain of person.nextPerson.nextPerson etc.
I assume I could stop trying to resolve nextPerson to an entity, instead set an ID, but I would like to reference the nextPerson for each person, so that isn't my desired approach.
I only wish to load entities and do not need to persist or delete any rows.
I have tried using different relationships such as OneToOne, but the error remained the same. From what I can tell though, the problem is the chaining of relationships.
Using an eager fetch type gives the same error.
No error is thrown if I only have one key, for example nextPerson and not previousPerson and the entities are returned correctly.
I don't think the duplicate question is similar in this scenario. My case is a unidirectional relationship to a row in the same table. Each row can point to 0-2 rows in the same table too.
